# Would a regular expression help this search string? IN: "abc d efg" OUT: ["%abc%","%efg%"]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, arrays, string

Could this code be optimised with a regex?

```
search = search.split.delete_if{|s|s.length==1}.map{|s|s="%#{s}%"}
```

It takes a string, splits it into an array and removes any elements with a length of 1 and wraps each string in percent symbols ready for SQL.

IN: `"abc d efg"` OUT: `["%abc%","%efg%"]`

Comment: With no benchmark evidence to support my theory, I would bet that this implementation is actually faster than a regex.

Comment: That's good to know, any advice on how to test?

Comment: How about trying Timecop to see if it's faster or slower? [https://github.com/jtrupiano/timecop](https://github.com/jtrupiano/timecop)

Comment: Also found [this](http://ruby.about.com/od/tasks/f/benchmark.htm) which I'm trying out and is quite useful too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works, but it benchmarks slower, I don't think a regex based solution is going to be faster.

```
string.scan(/\S{2,}/).map { |word| "%#{word}%" }
```

Avoiding duplicating arrays seems to be the fastest I can think of:

```
words = string.split
words.reject! { |s| s.length == 1 }
words.map! { |s| "%#{s}%" }
words
```